# Why my jQuery does not return to me the value of <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

My **index.html**:

```
<body>
   <select id="car">
    <option value="TOYOTA">TOYOTA</option>
    <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
    </select>

    <input type=button id="get_btn" value="Get"></input>

    <script src="myscript.js"></script>

</body>
```

**myscript.js**:

```
var btn=$('#get_btn');
btn.click(function(){

    var car= $('#car').val;
    alert(car);
});
```

When I press the get button, I expect an alert show the selected car, but I got an alert window with the jQuery **val** function code:

```
function (value) {
    if (!arguments.length) {
        var elem = this[0];
        if (elem) {
             ....
```

Where goes wrong?

Comment: Please edit your **index.html** and surround `button` with double quotes (as you did with other attribute values).

Comment: please don't make such silly mistakes and put it in **SO** you are missing `()` of `val()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

".val" is a function. Use:

```
var car= $('#car').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

`val` is a function, not a variable. You need to amend your **myscript.js** code as follows:

```
var btn=$('#get_btn');
btn.click(function(){
    var car = $('#car').val();
    alert(car);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have missing brackets :

```
var car= $('#car').val;
```

and should be :

```
var car= $('#car').val();
```